# Corner of skybox not rendering with increasing size

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I am trying to create a scene in visual studio using directX11, and I want to generate a skybox large enough to fit my terrain and other objects. I found that after a certain size, there appear to be areas around the corner that won't get rendered, and the gap increases with size. What could be the reason for this?

[image]

Here is my code for the skybox

```
SkyBox::SkyBox(ID3D11Device *dev, ShaderTexture* _pShader, float size)
{
    this->pShader = _pShader;
    this->pTexture = NULL;

    int nverts = 24;
    StandardVertex *pVerts = new StandardVertex[nverts];

    int ntri = 12;
    TriangleByIndex *pTriList = new TriangleByIndex[ntri];

    // Setting up faces
    // Forward
    int vind = 0;
    int tind = 0;
                    /* x     y     z    u      v   */
    pVerts[vind].set(-size, size, size, 1, 0.3334f);
    pVerts[vind + 1].set(size, size, size, 0.75f, 0.3334f);
    pVerts[vind + 2].set(size, -size, size, 0.75f, 0.666f);
    pVerts[vind + 3].set(-size, -size, size, 1, 0.666f);
    pTriList[tind].set(vind, vind + 1, vind + 2);
    pTriList[tind + 1].set(vind, vind + 2, vind + 3);

    // Back
    vind += 4;
    tind += 2;

    pVerts[vind].set(size, size, -size, 0.5f, 0.3334f);
    pVerts[vind + 1].set(-size, size, -size, 0.25f, 0.3334f);
    pVerts[vind + 2].set(-size, -size, -size, 0.25f, 0.666f);
    pVerts[vind + 3].set(size, -size, -size, 0.5f, 0.666f);
    pTriList[tind].set(vind, vind + 1, vind + 2);
    pTriList[tind + 1].set(vind, vind + 2, vind + 3);

    // Left
    vind += 4;
    tind += 2;
    pVerts[vind].set(-size, size, -size, 0.25f, 0.3334f);
    pVerts[vind + 1].set(-size, size, size, 0, 0.3334f);
    pVerts[vind + 2].set(-size, -size, size, 0, 0.666f);
    pVerts[vind + 3].set(-size, -size, -size, 0.25f, 0.666f);
    pTriList[tind].set(vind, vind + 1, vind + 2);
    pTriList[tind + 1].set(vind, vind + 2, vind + 3);

    // Right
    vind += 4;
    tind += 2;
    pVerts[vind].set(size, size, size, 0.75f, 0.3334f);
    pVerts[vind + 1].set(size, size, -size, 0.5f, 0.3334f);
    pVerts[vind + 2].set(size, -size, -size, 0.5f, 0.666f);
    pVerts[vind + 3].set(size, -size, size, 0.75f, 0.666f);
    pTriList[tind].set(vind, vind + 1, vind + 2);
    pTriList[tind + 1].set(vind, vind + 2, vind + 3);

    // Top
    vind += 4;
    tind += 2;

    pVerts[vind].set(-size, size, -size, 0.25f, 0.3333f);
    pVerts[vind + 1].set(size, size, -size, 0.5f, 0.3333f);
    pVerts[vind + 2].set(size, size, size, 0.5f, 0);
    pVerts[vind + 3].set(-size, size, size, 0.25f, 0);
    pTriList[tind].set(vind, vind + 1, vind + 2);
    pTriList[tind + 1].set(vind, vind + 2, vind + 3);

    // Bottom
    vind += 4;
    tind += 2;
    pVerts[vind].set(size, -size, -size, 0.5f, 0.6667f);
    pVerts[vind + 1].set(-size, -size, -size, 0.25f, 0.6667f);
    pVerts[vind + 2].set(-size, -size, size, 0.25f, 1);
    pVerts[vind + 3].set(size, -size, size, 0.5f, 1);
    pTriList[tind].set(vind, vind + 1, vind + 2);
    pTriList[tind + 1].set(vind, vind + 2, vind + 3);

    pModel = new Model(dev, pVerts, nverts, pTriList, ntri);

    delete[] pVerts;
    delete[] pTriList;
}
```

Comment: A better approach is to render a unit sphere (i.e. with a radius of one world unit) and simply write its pixels to the depth buffer's far plane in the pixel shader. This is better than scaling up a box or sphere to an arbitrary size such that it encompasses the game world.

Comment: The size of the cube shouldn't matter, I suggest you show us your shader code.

Comment: we need more info, my current guess at the moment is that the skybox corner exceeds the far plane of your camera and gets clipped. i recommend that instead of extending the size of your skybox as your scene grows in size, keep it to a reasonable fixed size, and then reposition it to the camera position periodically or on each frame render, so the camera is never able to reach its edges